# How to join the default bridge network with docker-compose v2?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I tried to setup an [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) container to access my other containers via subdomains on port 80 instead of special ports. As you can guess, I could not get it to work.

I'm kind of new to docker itself and found that it's more comfortable for me to write `docker-compose.yml` files so I don't have to constantly write long `docker run ...` commands. I thought there's no difference in how you start the containers, either with `docker` or `docker-compose`. However, one difference I noticed is that starting the container with `docker` does not create any new networks, but with `docker-compose` there will be a `xxx_default` network afterwards.

I read that containers on different networks cannot access each other and maybe that might be the reason why the nginx-proxy is not forwarding the requests to the other containers. However, I was unable to find a way to configure my `docker-compose.yml` file to not create any new networks, but instead join the default bridge network like `docker run` does.

I tried the following, but it resulted in an error saying that I cannot join system networks like this:

```
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: bridge
```

I also tried `network_mode: bridge`, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

How do I have to write the `docker-compose.yml` file to not create a new network, or is that not possible at all?

Bonus question: Are there any other differences between `docker` and `docker-compose` that I should know of?

Comment: [v1 format](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v1/) compose files won't create a new network, but require `links` to be setup to talk to other containers on the default bridge.

Comment: v1 is due to be deprecated, its use should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, I was using version 2 format. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: I just used that syntax for version 3 where it works just fine.
i did not use the default bridge but another one created by another docker-compose.yml containing the nginx. the remaining problem is the hostnames with the underscore in iit

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Adding `network_mode: bridge` to each service in your `docker-compose.yml` will stop compose from creating a network.

If any service is not configured with this bridge (or host), a network will be created.

Tested and confirmed with:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
  app:
    image: ubuntu:latest
    network_mode: bridge
```

Comment: This breaks discovery. So if you have >1 containers that need to talk to each other it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnEikenberry While it can make discovery tricky, it does not break it. The user can still use `links` syntax within compose.

Comment: Docker stacks don't support `network_mode`, is there a similar solution to making this work with them?

Comment: Docker Swarm has lost. Kubernetes has won. My advice? use `docker-compose.yml` was development only, stick to `version: 2.4` and forget `3` exists :+1:

Comment: In e a stack deploy you label the network as external in the networks stanza to achieve the same functionality as this in `docker-compose`

Comment: Beware that joining the default bridge will break DNS resolution of container names. So e.g. `ping app` will stop working.