# How to join the default bridge and user defined bridge with docker-compose v3?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have a docker-compose yml with several services which are in a user defined network (on bridge mode). I want to connect one on my service on the default docker bridge in order to expose a port to the outside world.

To summarize, there is a concrete example of what I want to do:

```
services:
  service1:
    networks:
      - my_network

  service2:
    networks:
      - my_network
      - bridge
    ports:
      8080:8080
```

As described [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network) I tried the following, but it resulted in this error:

> ERROR: for app  network-scoped alias is supported only for containers in user defined networks.

```yaml
networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
  bridge:
    external: true
```

I also tried the solution proposed in [How to join the default bridge network with docker-compose v2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43754095/how-to-join-the-default-bridge-network-with-docker-compose-v2), but you can't mix the keyword `network_mode: bridge` and the keyword `networks` in a docker compose.

I also tried to remove the reference to the default bridge network in the docker-compose.yml, and add my service2 container to the default bridge after starting the services, such as:

```
docker-compose up
docker network connect bridge service2
```

This approach works and I can access my exposed port on *service2* from the outside world, I end up with :

```json
docker inspect service2


"Networks": {
    "bridge": {
        ...
     },
     "my_network": {  
          ...
      }
}
```

But I don't want to execute the `docker network connect bridge service2` each time I want to start my services.

I know that my question is very similar with this one: [How to use the host network, and any other user-defined network together in Docker-Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47303141/how-to-use-the-host-network-and-any-other-user-defined-network-together-in-dock), except that I don't want to use the host mode.

Is there any way to connect a service on a user defined network and the default bridge at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you dont have to be on the default bridge network to publish ports from container to your machine.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for your answer, you solved my problem. But what if someone still wants to connect a service to both a user defined bridge and the default bridge ?

Comment: As Anthony said, this case is exactly what i need. I need my services to be in both - default one and user defined.

Comment: @Anthony, it looks like that is not possible, see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3012 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/3476

Comment: wow, you posted what should have been a comment as an answer.